# How to call method on struct that has mutable self in Rust

Tags: rust

I am having trouble with the following set up:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct SomeStruct {
    numbers: Vec<u32>,
}

impl SomeStruct {
    fn some_func(&mut self) { // `mut` causes the issue
        self.numbers.push(9); // Contrived but need to call self in here.
        println!("Hello from some func");
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let struct1 = SomeStruct {
        numbers: vec![1, 2, 3],
    };
    let struct2 = SomeStruct {
        numbers: vec![99, 98, 97],
    };

    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    vec.push(&struct1);
    vec.push(&struct2);

    let first = vec.first_mut().unwrap();

    // cannot borrow `**first` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
    // cannot borrow as mutable rustc(E0596)
    first.some_func();
}
```

There are many questions about mutable & borrowing but I still can't figure it out. Could someone please explain why this is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `vec` only has *shared* references, i.e. `&SomeStruct` instead of `SomeStruct` or `&mut SomeStruct`.

The call to `some_func()` can't succeed in this setup because it requires `&mut self`. However, there are ways to work around this:

1. let `vec` own `SomeStruct`, e.g.: `vec![struct1, struct2]`
2. Push `&mut struct1` and `&mut struct2` in the vec
3. use [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html), e.g. through `RefCell` which would allow you to modify data while holding a shared reference

The interior mutability solution would look something like this:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct SomeStruct {
    numbers: RefCell<Vec<u32>>,
}

impl SomeStruct {
    fn some_func(&self) {
        self.numbers.borrow_mut().push(9); // Contrived but need to call self in here.
        println!("Hello from some func");
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let struct1 = SomeStruct {
        numbers: RefCell::new(vec![1, 2, 3]),
    };
    let struct2 = SomeStruct {
        numbers: RefCell::new(vec![99, 98, 97]),
    };

    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    vec.push(&struct1);
    vec.push(&struct2);

    let first = vec.first().unwrap();

    // cannot borrow `**first` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
    // cannot borrow as mutable rustc(E0596)
    first.some_func();
}
```

Comment: I want to keep that as refs as it's very perf critical code (think the other way has copy cost?). Wonder if `borrow_mut` has runtime cost, will look into it otherwise use mut on the structs which works too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dominic Your intuition about performance of `Vec<&SomeStruct>` vs. `Vec<SomeStruct>` is very likely wrong. Write things in the most obvious and maintainable way first, then measure before you start adding `&`s in places where they cause problems. Yes, by the way, `borrow_mut()` does have a (small) runtime cost.

Comment: @Dominic If it's the size of the struct you're concerned about, consider putting it inside a `Box` (or `Rc`/`Arc` for sharing). `Box<Vec<SomeStruct>>` has exactly the same size and, once created, is as cheap to use as `&Vec<SomeStruct>`, but doesn't need to borrow. Either way, though (`Box` or `&`), you pay a stiff penalty for adding a layer of indirection, which is likely to cancel out any advantage you get from making the type smaller, unless you do a lot more passing-around than you do dereferencing. Only profiling can say for sure.